# SQL Agent parsing actually executes instead of just validating

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-agent

I'm seeing some really odd behavior with SSMS 2014/2016 that I stumbled accross by pure accident.  This was run on SQL2014 SP1+CU6 (the fixed one) in a non-prod environment. Here's the backstory.

I use SQL Compare to deploy changes to our SQL servers.  We are moving to a TFS/DB Project approach but this is what we are using right now.

Let's say one of the changes is to add a column to a table.  This is the code that SQL Compare generates for that change:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
USE [DBA_Support]
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[ParseExec]'
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParseExec] ADD
[BlockType] [int] NULL
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
DECLARE @Success AS BIT
SET @Success = 1
SET NOEXEC OFF
IF (@Success = 1) PRINT 'The database update succeeded'
ELSE BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'The database update failed'
END
GO
```

Seems legit, and it is.  Load it into an Agent job step, Parse it, no issues.

Let's take it one step further, what happens if you sausage finger the `Paste` button and accidentally hit it twice, or Ctl+V twice.  You get the code, stacked twice, as shown below:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
USE [DBA_Support]
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[ParseExec]'
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParseExec] ADD
[BlockType] [int] NULL
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
DECLARE @Success AS BIT
SET @Success = 1
SET NOEXEC OFF
IF (@Success = 1) PRINT 'The database update succeeded'
ELSE BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'The database update failed'
END
GO

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
USE [DBA_Support]
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[ParseExec]'
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParseExec] ADD
[BlockType] [int] NULL
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
DECLARE @Success AS BIT
SET @Success = 1
SET NOEXEC OFF
IF (@Success = 1) PRINT 'The database update succeeded'
ELSE BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'The database update failed'
END
GO
```

Here's the odd behavior, in SSMS, we get `The command was parsed successfully` but, it **actually performs the operation on the table**:

And, no, it wasn't on the table before the parsing, I double checked.

[image]

Has anyone ever seen this happen.  I can't help think that it has something to with a SET option or the fact that we are suing SERIAL transactions.  Regardless of that, should the `Parse` button simply hit the algebrizer, validate that everything is legit and not actually execute anything?

Is this a bug or am I just overlooking something simple here?

Comment: And this only happens within SQL Agent's half-functional editor UI? Personally, even without knowing about this, I would be parsing in a regular, fully-functional query window.

Comment: Correct, only in the Agent UI.  SSMS query window parses and doesn't execute.  It was sheer dumb luck that I came across this as I usually parse the scripts in our sandbox using SSMS, this time I got in a hurry and presto, I found this little monster.  This is fairly scary behavior as you could accidentally make a change.  Is this worth a connect item or some sort of feedback to MS?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a good Connect item (but I would use a generic and self-enclosed repro, like one that creates the table first, and drops it afterward).

Comment: Sounds good.  I'll build it all out so it can be easily repro'd and submit a Connect item.  Thanks for the advice, Aaron.

Comment: That said, I don't know that I would expect a fix. I've probably submitted 30 Connect items against SQL Agent dialogs alone and I don't believe a single one of them has ever been addressed.

Comment: Understood, it's worth a shot and definitely something to be wary of.  Needless to say, I'll be parsing in SSMS only from here on out!

Comment: I figured out what's making it execute but the question is SHOULD it.  The `SET NOEXEC OFF` option. "When SET NOEXEC is OFF, all batches are executed after compilation."  But then it goes on to say "The setting of SET NOEXEC is set at execute or run time and not at parse time."  So, it shouldn't even look at the NOEXEC until execution time, right?  It seems that it's actually picking this up at parse time.  Still think it's worth a Connect item?

Comment: If the behavior is different between a query window and the Agent UI, yes.